# RegExp replace substring in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a few signal flags in a serialized string and I need to remove the flag from the string when the user requests a certain operation.
I was unable to find a regex that works in all cases for the below string.

```
var flags = "out:ab,bc,bcc,cd";
```

This is the closest I got (e.g. removing bc flag)

```
flags.replace(/[:,]bc\b/, "");
```

Result is `out:ab,bcc,cd` which is cool, but when removing ab I will get `outbc,bcc,cd` which is wrong. The result must always keep the string serialized, e.g. `out:flag1,flag2`
I tried capturing subpatterns but could not find an all-round working combo.

-- more info:

Flags are 0/1 signals, if a flag is present I must remove it.

Out: is the operation mode and it's the opposite of In: (this is a second group of flags). To put it simple, Out: is a "allow all, but blacklist these", where In: is "deny all, but whitelist these". The app can run in either mode. ab, bc, cd ... are sample alphabetical keys.

Comment: So what are the "flags"? What's `out`? What's the expected output? That would clear things a bit.

Comment: If you want to match something but not replace it, use [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: @elclanrs I added more info hope it's clearer now.


Barmar I need to remove the flag, not just match :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `non-capturing parentheses`:

```
var q = ['cd', 'bc'].join('|'),
    re = new RegExp('(?:[:]('+q+'))|(,('+q+')(?=,))|(,('+q+')$)', 'g'),
    flags = "out:ab,bc,bcc,cd";
flags.replace(re, '');
=> "out:ab,bcc"
```

From MDN's [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

> (?:x) Matches 'x' but does not remember the match. The parentheses are called non-capturing parentheses, and let you define subexpressions for regular expression operators to work with. Consider the sample expression /(?:foo){1,2}/. Without the non-capturing parentheses, the {1,2} characters would apply only to the last 'o' in 'foo'. With the capturing parentheses, the {1,2} applies to the entire word 'foo'.

---

**Edit:** An explanation of the RegExp

```
/(?:[:](cd|bc))|(,(cd|bc)(?=,))|(,(cd|bc)$)/g
```

There are three sections, separated by pipes. `?:[:](cd|bc)` covers flags right after the semicolon; `,(cd|bc)(?=,)` covers flags between commas, including the preceding comma in the matched expression; `,(cd|bc)$` covers flags at the end of the string, also including the preceding comma.

---

**Edit 2:**

Fixed RegExp, replace `q` with the flags you want to match.

Comment: Hm removing `ab` still removes `:`

Comment: I think I got it: `/(?:\bab\b(?:,)?)|(,ab(?=,))|(,ab$)/g` I changed the first section and removed the ORs since there's no use case that would need removing two or more at a time.

Comment: Also, `/((?:ab|bcc|cd),)|(,(?:ab|bcc|cd)(?=,))|(,?(?:ab|bcc|cd)$)/g` --> http://jsfiddle.net/dXtDu/

Comment: Cool, I added some additional groups and they all seem to be processed correctly. http://jsfiddle.net/dXtDu/1/ Thanks!